# Angularjs $http.post or $http({ returning all html

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, php-5.3

Hey helpful people   I have an array in javascript and would like to send it to a php file currently the array is empty but could throw anything in it i suppose

here is the javascript

```
$scope.save = function(){
var savedArray = [];
var request = $http({
    method: "post",
    url:"test.php",
    data: {
      array: savedArray
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  });

  request.success(function(data){
    $scope.message = "FROM PHP FILE "+data;
  });
  }
```

the php code is

```
<?php
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);

@$array = $request->array;
echo $array;
?>
```

now the problem is that no matter what data is returning all the html without it ever going to the php page i have tried commenting out echo $array and print_r on all the variables but nothing is returning anything

any suggestions on what to do next?

Comment: In the AJAX headers, you try to send an array with name savedArray, which is undefined in the currently posted code. Try changing it to 'array' like the name of the variable you have.

Comment: you are setting request as `form-urlencoded` but trying to decode as json at server. Pick one or the other , can't mix them.

Comment: @victor175 thanks for pointing that out it was just a mistake in copying my code over

Comment: @charlietfl removing the header did not change anything

Comment: well also note that you can't echo array. Inspect the actual request itself in browser dev tools network for more clues ...sent/received/status etc

Comment: @charlietfl excellent point  however even var_dump() returns nothing  infact if i comment out all the php code it still returns all the html as if its never going to the php page however if i rename test.php to something else it returns a 404 wether the code is commented out or not

Comment: and the dev tools network inspection details?

Comment: @charlietfl shows status code 200 ok request method post the url shows the response header and request header (request shows application/json, text/plain, */* blah blah blah)  then the bottom shows the request playlod and the array which i can read properly and its the data i want in the php page  it just dosent seem to go there